# Replace underscores for spaces in all the hyperlinks

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replace all the underscores for spaces in all the links within the following page:

[All-cars](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/autofs/shared/tourvista/index.html)

Unfortunately it doesn't work with fewer cars:

[Alfa-Romeo](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/autofs/shared/tourvista/alfa_romeo/index.html)

As you can see it only deletes the first 4 underscores. Maybe one underscore for each

element?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#content li").each(function() { $(this).each( function () {
     $("a").each ( function () {
       $(this).text( $(this).text().replace("_", " ") ); // replace
     }) })
   });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use with **[JavaScript RegExp g Modifier](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp)** for replacing all occurrence:

```
$("#content li a").each(function(){
   $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/_/g, " "));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3wkqc308/)**

Comment: is /g stands for global and used to replace all available underscores?

Comment: @SP007: yes. its for global match. see this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `text()` with a regular expression:

```
$('#content li a').text(function(i, t){
    return t.replace(/_/g, ' ');
});
```

References:

- [Javascript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`text()`](http://api.jQuery.com/text/).